# How to install Bloomberg API Library for Python 2.7 on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, bloomberg

I'm trying to setup my Mac OS X system to use the `pdblp` Python library which requires me to first install the [Bloomberg Open API libary for Python](https://www.bloomberglabs.com/api/libraries/). After cloning the git repo and running `python setup.py install`, I get

```
File "setup.py", line 20, in <module>
  raise Exception("BLPAPI_ROOT environment variable isn't defined")
Exception: BLPAPI_ROOT environment variable isn't defined
```

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 5):

You also need to install the [C/C++ libraries](https://bloomberg.bintray.com/BLPAPI-Experimental-Generic/blpapi_cpp_3.8.1.1-darwin.tar.gz) and then set BLPAPI_ROOT to the location of the `libblpapi3_32.so` or `libblpapi3_64.so` files. For example:

```
cd /some/directory
wget https://bloomberg.bintray.com/BLPAPI-Experimental-Generic/blpapi_cpp_3.8.1.1-darwin.tar.gz
tar zxvf blpapi_cpp_3.8.1.1-darwin.tar.gz
```

<strike>`export BLPAPI_ROOT=/some/directory/blpapi_cpp_3.8.1.1/Darwin`</strike>

```
export BLPAPI_ROOT=/some/directory/blpapi_cpp_3.8.1.1
```

Then you can proceed with installing the python library.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am stuck at following     blpapi/internals_wrap.cxx:3105:10: fatal error: 'blpapi_types.h' file not found
    #include "blpapi_types.h"
             ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. You answer is almost correct. For export variable, it works finde - if you just write it as export BLPAPI_ROOT=/some/directory/blpapi_cpp_3.8.1.1

Comment: Confirmed that you must export BLPAPI_ROOT=/some/directory/blpapi_cpp_3.8.1.1

Answer (score 5):

Just to complete the question (thanks mob :)

Packages Source - https://www.bloomberglabs.com/api/libraries/

Preparation

1. SDK for C/C++
2. SDK for Python

Instructions

```
# navigate yourself to the path where you want to keep your SDK for some tim
cd /Users/msam/

# unzip C/C++ Package
tar zxvf Downloads/blpapi_cpp_3.8.1.1-darwin.tar.gz

# set variable
export BLPAPI_ROOT=/some/directory/blpapi_cpp_3.8.1.1/
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/sampathkumarm/blpapi_cpp_3.8.1.1/Darwin/

# save variable to reuse in next session
echo >> ~/.bash_profile
echo "Bloomberg API (python)library Settings " >> ~/.bash_profile
echo "export BLPAPI_ROOT=/some/directory/blpapi_cpp_3.8.1.1/" >> ~/.bash_profile
echo "export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/sampathkumarm/blpapi_cpp_3.8.1.1/Darwin/"  >> ~/.bash_profile
echo >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Ref:
 1. [python blpapi installation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32026901/python-blpapi-installation-error)